Python MySQL connect changing the address when trying to connect
According to the mysql connect python documentation, to make a simple connection there is only the need to do the following
connection = mysql.connector.connect(
   host='135.113.***.***',
   user='root',
   password='r00tr00t',
   database='mysql',
   port=32105
)

However, when trying this it fails because the host address is changed to another one that is unrecognizable to us, as follows:
>>> connection = mysql.connector.connect(
   host='135.113.***.***',
   user='root',
   password='r00tr00t',
   database='mysql',
   port=32105,
)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/opt/python312/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 179, in connect
   return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "/opt/python312/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 95, in __init__
   self.connect(**kwargs)
 File "/opt/python312/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 716, in connect
   self._open_connection()
 File "/opt/python312/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 208, in _open_connection
   self._do_auth(self._user, self._password,
 File "/opt/python312/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 144, in _do_auth
   self._auth_switch_request(username, password)
 File "/opt/python312/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 177, in _auth_switch_request
   raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'::ffff:172.17.12.105' (using password: YES)
>>>

Does anybody have any idea why the mysql.connector.connect is generating this IP address and causing the stated issue or is this a known unfixed issue?

I don't have a full answer, but my guess is that it has something to do with IPv6? Addresses starting with ::ffff: are transistion addresses. Additionally, you've setup your MySQL server such that login via root is not possible, you need to use a different user to access, or re-configure MySQL.
